# Getting UnicodeDecodeError while accessing csv file

Tags: python, python-3.2, python-unicode

Input file : chars.csv :

```
4,,x,,2,,9.012,2,,,,
6,,y,,2,,12.01,Â±4,,,,
7,,z,,2,,14.01,_3,,,,
```

When I try to parse this file, I get this error even after specifying utf-8 encoding.

```
>>> f=open('chars.csv',encoding='utf-8')
>>> f.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 36: invalid start byte
```

How to correct this error?

Version: Python 3.2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file  is clearly not utf-8 encoded, so you have at least those options:

- `f=open('chars.csv', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')` if given file is mostly utf-8 and you don't care about some small data loss. For other `errors` parameter values [check manual](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#open)
- simply use proper encoding, like latin-1, if you know one

Answer (score 0):

This is not UTF-8 encoding.  The UTF-8 encoding of ± is \xC2\xB1 and Â is \xC2\x83.  As RobertT suggested, try Latin-1:

```
f=open('chars.csv',encoding='latin-1')
```